# Crack WPA2 with username

Tags: wpa2, password-cracking

As far as I know you can crack WPA2-connections if you have the four-way-handshake. Then your program calculates the PMK/PTK and you get the key for the network. But what is with a WPA2-network where you have to use your password and your username for authentication? Is this only possible in WPA2-enterprise-networks, and can you crack them, too?